# EditText duplication issue with two-way data binding in Android application

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

this is my first time developing a small Android application.
I've got a weird Problem where a EditText field seems to duplicate when trying to use a two way data binding.
[image]
Its only possible to edit the text of the EditText field without the databinding therefore it is not possible to receive the Data.
[image]

The fragment layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".view.StartView">


    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.example.emitester2.viewModel.StartViewModel" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/StartWrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@={viewmodel.username}"
            android:hint="@string/UsernameHint"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/usernameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@{viewmodel.username}"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startQuizButton"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/start_quiz"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

The Fragment Java source file:

```java
package com.example.emitester2.view;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;

import com.example.emitester2.R;
import com.example.emitester2.databinding.FragmentStartViewBinding;
import com.example.emitester2.viewModel.StartViewModel;

public class StartView extends Fragment {

    private StartViewModel startViewModel;


    public static StartView newInstance() {
        return new StartView();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,@Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start_view, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        FragmentStartViewBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this.getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_start_view);
        startViewModel = new StartViewModel();
        binding.setViewmodel(startViewModel);
        binding.executePendingBindings();
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.startQuizButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startQuiz(v);
            }
        });
    }

    public void startQuiz(View view) {
        // This is probably not the right way to do this, but it works for now

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        String username = this.startViewModel.getStringUsername();
        bundle.putString("username",username);
        NavController navController;
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);
        navController.navigate(R.id.action_startView_to_quizView,bundle);
    }

}
```

The Viewmodel:

```java
package com.example.emitester2.viewModel;

import androidx.databinding.ObservableField;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;

public class StartViewModel {
    public ObservableField<String> username;

    public StartViewModel() {
        username = new ObservableField<>("John Doe");
    }

    public String getStringUsername() {
        System.out.println(username);
        //for testing purposes
        username.set("Jane Doe");
        return username.get();
    }

    public void demofunction(){
        System.out.println(username);
        getStringUsername();
    }
}
```

I am navigating via a NavGraph where this fragment is the initial starting point.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/startView">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/startView"
        android:name="com.example.emitester2.view.StartView"
        android:label="fragment_start_view"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_start_view" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_startView_to_quizView"
            app:destination="@id/quizView" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/quizView"
        android:name="com.example.emitester2.view.QuizView"
        android:label="fragment_quiz_view"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_quiz_view" />
</navigation>
```

I use a second fragment with similar structure where the EditText Field works fine with a two way databinding and the IDE throws no error when building the project. I've got no clue where to search anymore and I would be happy if anyone could point me in the right direction.